# Display ACF if parent page has specific template

Tags: page-template, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to make a new ACF rule to display fields when parent page has a specific template name. Here's my current attempt:

```
add_filter('acf/location/rule_types', 'acf_location_rules_types');
function acf_location_rules_types( $choices ) {

    $choices['Parent']['parent_template'] = 'Parent Template';

    return $choices;

}

add_filter('acf/location/rule_values/parent_template', 'acf_location_rules_values_parent_template');
function acf_location_rules_values_parent_template( $choices ) {

    $templates = get_page_templates();

    if ( $templates ) {
        foreach ( $templates as $template_name => $template_filename ) {

            $choices[ $template_name ] = $template_name;

        }
    }

    return $choices;
}

add_filter('acf/location/rule_match/parent_template', 'acf_location_rules_match_parent_template', 10, 3);
function acf_location_rules_match_parent_template( $match, $rule, $options ) {

    $selected_template = $rule['value'];

    global $post;
    $template = get_page_template_slug( $post->post_parent );

    if( $rule['operator'] == "==" ) {

        $match = ( $selected_template == $template );

    } elseif($rule['operator'] == "!=") {

        $match = ( $selected_template != $template );

    }

    return $match;
}
```

I think the problem is the way I am trying to get parent page template for current page. Can I even get parent page template inside a hook function inside function.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone dealing with the same issue, I just needed to change:

```
$choices[ $template_name ] = $template_name;
```

with:

```
$choices[ $template_filename ] = $template_name;
```

Consider a page template `Homepage (page-home.php)`. This way the template name `Homepage` will appear on the custom fields page but `$rule['value']` will actually return `page-home.php` and then we can compare this with `get_page_template_slug( $post->post_parent )`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the way you're getting the parent page nor its template. You can do it exactly like you do.

Problem lies in these two lines:

```
$choices[ $template_name ] = $template_name;
...
$match = ( $selected_template == $template );
```

So you're setting template name as choices, but you compare it with filename of the template.

Change the first one to

```
$choices[ $template_filename ] = $template_name;
```

And it will work correctly.